# How to take input from one of the two textboxes in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on a browser where I have two text boxes, one for URL and one for direct google search. I want to take input from one of the two textboxes. I also want to check if URL is valid or not. If not, it should directly google the text entered.

XML:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="https://"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter url"
    android:padding="5dp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Java:

```
bt1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        address = et1.getText ( ).toString ( );
        String [] split = address.split ("//");
        if(split[1].length ()!=0) {
            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl (address)){}
            else {
                address = "https://www.google.com#q=" + address;
            }
        }
        else{
            String gaddress = et2.getText().toString();
            address = "https://www.google.com#q=" + gaddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: It doesn't show any error. It just crashes when i enter text in 2nd text box

Comment: can you post the error log? when crashing?

Comment: where do you use the address variable after onclick even? post those code segments as well if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(split[1].length ()!=0) {
```

to

```
if (split.length >= 1 && split[1].length() != 0) {
```

to stop current ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: answer updated, check it and post the error log if the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

split() can not be called on null values. So before the split. check whether the string is empty or not. A better way of doing it, is below. Of course there are many ways to go for it. This is just a one.

```
bt1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        address = et1.getText ( ).toString ( );
        if(!address.trim().equals("")) {
          String [] split = address.split ("//");
          if(split[1].length ()!=0) {
              if (URLUtil.isValidUrl (address)){}
              else {
                address = "https://www.google.com#q=" + address;
              }
          }
        }
        else{
            String gaddress = et2.getText().toString();
            address = "https://www.google.com#q=" + gaddress;
        }
    }
}
```